# iphone crash report doesn't show latest app's crash info

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode7, crash-reports

I need to get crash report of my app on iphone 4s (ios 9.2.1), it crashes many times but crash report/logs doesn't show last crashes info, only old info, I make sync for iphone by iTunes many times but without success.
I'm working on Xcode 7.2.

What that mean ? or how can I get the latest crash logs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a crash logs limit, but it's about 150 or 200 logs. If you reached that number - just clean your logs.

Edit: to clean the logs, go to xcode -> window -> Devices -> then choose your device and press View Device Logs. There you can select all the logs and delete them.

Comment: Tried this but no luck